# How to autoscroll when adding new message to chat?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm doing a chat app, i would like the ChatView to autoscroll to the last message when added and also on appear (when i open a long chat from the history records), basically, always autoscroll to bottom. I have tried onChange, onReceive, etc but had no luck. When i add a new message it does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ChatView: View {
    var chatId: UUID
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @FocusState private var isEditing
    @EnvironmentObject var chatViewModel: ChatViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { _ in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(chatViewModel.chats.filter { $0.id == chatId }) { chat in
                            ForEach(chat.messages) { message in
                                messageView(message: message)
                            }
                        }
                        if chatViewModel.isWaitingForResponse {
                            HStack {
                                ProgressView("Waiting for response...")
                                    .progressViewStyle(.circular)
                                    .tint(Theme.secondaryColor)
                                    .padding()
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a message...", text: $chatViewModel.currentTextInput, axis: .vertical)
                    .padding()
                    .lineLimit(5)
                    .onAppear {
                        isEditing = true
                    }
                    .focused($isEditing)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(Theme.secondaryColor)
                    )
                if !chatViewModel.currentTextInput.isEmpty {
                    Button {
                        if !chatViewModel.currentTextInput.isEmpty {
                            chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId, message: chatViewModel.currentTextInput)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: Theme.gradients, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                    }
                } else {
                    Button {} label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: Theme.gradients, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                    }
                    Button {} label: {
                        Image(systemName: "mic.circle")
                            .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: Theme.gradients, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .background(colorScheme == .dark ? Theme.darkBackground : Theme.lightBackground)
    }

    func messageView(message: Message) -> some View {
        HStack {
            if message.role == .user { Spacer() }
            Text(message.content)
                .padding()
                .background(message.role == .user ? Theme.secondaryColor : Theme.tertiaryColor)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            if message.role == .assistant || message.role == .system { Spacer() }
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChatView(chatId: UUID())
            .environmentObject(ChatView.ChatViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: try this: identify your list entries, eg using `.id(...)` then use the `ScrollViewReader{ reader in ...}` together with `.onChange(...)` that includes  `reader.scrollTo(...)` inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Reverse Scroll view in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383130/custom-reverse-scroll-view-in-swiftui)